# PHP OCI8 bind by name in function with date datatype

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I have to call a procedure in an Oracle DB.
the procedure is like:

```
procedure test
  (a IN VARCHAR2
  ,b IN INTEGER
  ,c OUT DATE)
```

I'm calling the procedure as

```
$sql="BEGIN test(:a, :b, :c); END;";

$smt = oci_parse($db, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($smt, ':a', $a);
oci_bind_by_name($smt, ':b', $b);
oci_bind_by_name($smt, ':c', $c);
$results = oci_execute($smt);
```

When c is empty, everything works fine.
But when it has a value, I get this error

```
oci_execute(): ORA-06502: PL
/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1&#039;
```

How can I set the data type as date on calling a producere on a out variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented on the [`oci_bind_by_name` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php):

> You must specify maxlength when using an OUT bind so that PHP allocates enough memory to hold the returned value.

So simply changing:

```
oci_bind_by_name($smt, ':c', $c);
```

to:

```
oci_bind_by_name($smt, ':c', $c, 100); // NOTE: 100 is arbitrary.
```

should solve the problem.